# fftw how to use the fftw and opencv to decomposed image into its magnitude and phase

Tags: c++, c, matlab, opencv, fftw

Currently I have an image loaded in using opencv and trying to decompose it into its magnitude and phase components with fftw_plan_dft_2d. here is my code, but i could not obtain the correct result.
Edit(added from comment): i had finished the code in matlab,and i just try to convert the matlab code to c/c++, but i am not sure it is corrctely decomposed into magnitude and phase in this way

```
int main(){

    cv::Mat img1=cv::imread("Lena.bmp",0);
    cv::Mat img2;

    fftw_complex    *in;
    fftw_complex    *fft;        
    fftw_plan       p;
    int nx=img1.rows;
    int ny=img1.cols;

    int i,j;

    img2=img1.clone();

    in =  ( fftw_complex* )fftw_malloc( sizeof( fftw_complex ) * nx * ny );
    fft = ( fftw_complex* )fftw_malloc( sizeof( fftw_complex ) * nx * ny );

    int **x=new int*[nx];
    for(i=0;i<nx;i++)
        x[i]=new int[ny];

    int **y=new int*[nx];
    for(i=0;i<nx;i++)
        y[i]=new int[ny];

    for(i=0;i<nx;i++)
        for(j=0;j<ny;j++)
        {
            x[i][j]=j+1;
            y[i][j]=i+1;
        }
    for( i = 0; i < nx ; i++ ) {
        for( j = 0 ; j < ny ; j++ ) {
            in[i*ny+j][0] =( ( double )img1.data[i * ny + j]*pow(-1,x[i][j]+y[i][j]));
            in[i*ny+j][1] = 0.0;
        }
    }

    p = fftw_plan_dft_2d( nx , ny, in, fft,  FFTW_FORWARD,  FFTW_ESTIMATE );
         // perform FFT
      fftw_execute( p );


    cv::Mat mag(img1.size(),img1.type());
    cv::Mat pha(img1.size(),img1.type());

    double **magf=new double*[nx];
    for(i=0;i<nx;i++)
        magf[i]=new double[ny];

    double **phaf=new double*[nx];
    for(i=0;i<nx;i++)
        phaf[i]=new double[ny];

    fftw_complex *e = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*nx*ny);

    float pi=3.14156;
    for(i=0;i<nx;i++)
        for(j=0;j<ny;j++)
        {
            /*fft[i*ny+j][0]/=(double)nx*ny;
            fft[i*ny+j][1]/=(double)nx*ny;*/
            magf[i][j]=(double)sqrt(pow(fft[i*ny+j][0],2.0)+pow(fft[i*ny+j][1],2.0));
            phaf[i][j]=atan2(fft[i*ny+j][0],fft[i*ny+j][1]);
            e[i*ny+j][0]=cos(phaf[i][j]);
            e[i*ny+j][1]=sin(phaf[i][j]);
        }

    for(i=0;i<nx;i++)
        for(j=0;j<ny;j++)
        {
            mag.data[i*ny+j]=magf[i][j];
        }

    cv::namedWindow("magnitude",1);
    cv::imshow("magnitude",mag);

    fftw_complex* G= (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*nx*ny);
    fftw_complex* H= (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*nx*ny);
    for(i=0;i<nx;i++)
        for(j=0;j<ny;j++)
        {
            G[i*ny+j][0]=magf[i][j]*e[i*ny+j][0];
            G[i*ny+j][1]=magf[i][j]*e[i*ny+j][1];
        }

    p = fftw_plan_dft_2d(nx,ny, G, H, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    //// normalize IFFT result
      for( i = 0 ; i < ( nx * ny ) ; i++ ) {
          H[i][0] /= ( double )( nx * ny );
      }

    //  // copy IFFT result to img2's data
    for( i = 0 ; i < nx ; i++ ) {
        for( j = 0 ; j < ny ; j++ ) {
            img2.data[i * ny + j] = ( uchar )(H[i * ny + j][0]*pow(-1,x[i][j]+y[i][j]));
        }
    }


    cv::namedWindow("recover",1);
    cv::imshow("recover",img2);

    /*cv::namedWindow( "original_image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cv::namedWindow( "IFFT", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cv::imshow( "original_image", img1 );
    cv::imshow( "IFFT", img2 );

    cv::waitKey(0);*/
    cv::waitKey(0);
    fftw_destroy_plan( p );
    //fftw_destroy_plan( plan_b );
    fftw_free( in );
    fftw_free( fft );
    //fftw_free( ifft );


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to specify exactly what you did and tried. People won't help you unless you showed that you put some effort in it yourself. How do you know you don't get the correct results, what is the correct result?

Comment: yep. i had finished the code in matlab,and i just try to convert the matlab code to c/c++, but i am not sure it is corrctely decomposed into magnitude and phase in this way!

Comment: So add this information to your question and maybe add the tags matlab and c/c++ to it to attract people who work with both.

Comment: Thanks for your tips！It is the first time to ask question in this forums...